# Browser extension (Firefox/Chrome) to show what 'scripts' are on the current web page?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, browser-addons, noscript

I use [NoScript](http://noscript.net/) in Firefox (and [ScriptSafe](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/scriptsafe/oiigbmnaadbkfbmpbfijlflahbdbdgdf?hl=en) in Chrome), and I especially love the way that NoScript tells you exactly *how many* scripts (and objects) it's blocking on the current page.

But I've often wanted to know JUST WHAT those scripts are. If I can only look at the code of said scripts (isolated and listed nicely), I'll be able to get more an impression of what I'm protecting myself from or at least be able to load them directly from a clickable list of their extracted .js URL paths and explore them easily that way.

I'm aware of [Ghostery](https://www.ghostery.com/) and things like that (and use several such extensions) but although Ghostery does list 'things' it blocks for you, I don't think that quite fits the brief of what I'm after. I need something that shows the ENTIRE list (just whatever NoScript produces a number for, and a bonus would be to display 'objects' as well), extracted in a neat list somehow.

Is there some advanced feature or function in NoScript that I've never noticing, or something else that can do the job?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Almost every browser has **Developer Tools** nowadays. For Firefox though besides the in-built tools **Firebug** is really useful:

[image: 1]

Chrome Dev Tools:

[image: 2]

Comment: Sorry to seem a moron, but I've tried both FF and Chrome's Dev Tools and can't easily find the scripts list in both like your screenshots are showing. A clear instruction set would be great for both me and future pilgrims wondering how to do this as too! :) thanks

Comment: The first screenshot is from Firebug as I had noted above. Regarding Chrome's Dev Tools, be sure to check under both the Sources and Resources tabs. I got the screenshot directly from a Google help page, but it might be slightly out of date (I prefer and use Firefox+Firebug myself).

Answer (score 0):

Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> will open Chrome's Developer's Tools.

Or, `Options` -> `Tools` -> `Developer Tools`.